# PHPUnit cannot find classes namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit

I'm trying to run some unit tests using PHPUnit, but, when I use the command line to test, my test class cannot find the namespace from my main class.

This is my folder structure:

```
data/ 
src/
    Dao/
    Entity/
        City.php
    Facade/
    SplClassLoader.php 
tests/
    Entity/
        CityTest.php
    bootstrap.php
    phpunit.xml 
vendor/ 
composer.json 
composer.lock
```

This is the content of one of my classes inside /src/Entity/

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

class City
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;
```

my phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="../vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And my CityTest.php

```
<?php

class CityTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testAdd()
    {
        $city = new Entity\City(1, "London");
    }
}
```

When I run the command `phpunit tests/Entity/CityTest.php` I got this message error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Entity\City' not found

What can I do to fix this problem?

Thank you.

**Update**

I've resolved my problem with some updates. Here is my final folder structure:

```
data/  
src/  
tests/  
vendor/
composer.json*  
composer.lock*
phpunit.xml*
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
        >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*"
  },

  "config": {
    "process-timeout": 600,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "github-protocols": ["https"]
  },

  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "src/"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to add the source code of your project to Composer using "autoload".

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading